# How can I make spring.xml's xsi:schemaLocation work when my app is offline (finished product is an offline artifact)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application which will only work offline but because of how the project is setup it requires an internet connection start-up. I know the issue is the xsi:schemaLocation attribute in the spring.xml, but don't know Spring well enough to know how to set a project up pointing to the schemas locally.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.5.xsd">
```

does anybody have any experience here?

Comment: Which application server?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner what are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ommit the version numbers from the schema's, they will be loaded from the jar files, so

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
```

Before Spring jar's are released, the version is stripped off and the schemas are packaged with the jars. Its even a good practice to use the schema's without the version as it may point to classpath/version mismatch early